# Kernel of R-module homomorphism inclusion

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Let $f:M \rightarrow N$ be an R-module homomorphism with $X$ being a submodule of $M$ and $Y$ being a submodule of $N$.

Prove that $Kerf \subseteq f^{-1}(Y)$.

I've previously proven that $f(X)$ is a submodule of $N$ and that $f^{-1}(Y)$ is a submodule of $M$, but I really have no idea how to approach this proof and I would need some help. Thanks!

Comment: $m\in\mathrm{ker}(f)$ if and only if $f(m)=0_N$. $f^{-1}(Y) = \{m\in M\mid f(m)\in Y\}$. What is the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tbh this is a very simple problem and if you're struggling with it that's a sign you need to rethink how you approach proofs, and/or give more thought to the problem before giving up and asking for help. Let me give you a rundown of what your thought process should be on a problem like this.

1. you are supposed to prove an inclusion of sets $A\subseteq B$. So you should always start by assuming $x\in A$, applying the definition of whatever $A$ is, and trying to deduce $x\in B$.
2. in our case we are supposed to prove $\ker(f)\subseteq f^{-1}(Y)$. So suppose $x\in\ker(f)$. Now you should apply the definition of the kernel: by definition, $x\in\ker(f)$ means $f(x)=0_N$.
3. we want to prove that $x\in f^{-1}(Y)$, which means we want to prove that $f(x)\in Y$. But we know that $f(x)=0_N$, so we want to know that $0_N\in Y$. But this is part of the definition of $Y$ being a submodule of $N$.